# Chrome test automation strange display errors

Tags: css, google-chrome, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

we use Chromedriver to run automated tests in Chrome and recently we are getting strange display errors. It's like Chromedriver doesn't load the pages fully - text is missing, images are flipped or stretched, the layout is messed up - this happens not only on 'our' pages but on every URL we use. Once you manually resize the window the display becomes correct up until the webdriver does the next step.

The tests still work normally but screenshots after failed steps are basically useless. It didn't use to be this way. We use chromedriver 2.29 and chrome 57.0.2987.133 (basically latest version of both) on Mac OS X. I cannot find any existing issues about this problem.

Comment: I have this issue also - I haven't been able to locate the problem yet.

Comment: Do you have svg files on your site? blarblar.svg etc.